# Clash with \usepackage[<options>]{hyperref} and beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

When I use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Berkeley}      
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DeepPink4}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DarkRed}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=DarkBlue}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\title[something]{something}
 \author{someone}
 \date{someday}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{something}
 \justifying
 \href{http://google.com}{Google}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

I receive the error:

```
`option clash for package hyperref. \hypersetup`
```

However, when I suppress `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`  it works, but without the colour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 51):

`beamer` already loads `hyperref` internally, so you attempt produces a clash. You can pass the options to the class using the `hyperref` key (there are also `pgf`, `color` and `xcolor` keys to pass options to the corresponding packages):

```
\documentclass[
  xcolor={svgnames},
  hyperref={colorlinks,citecolor=DeepPink4,linkcolor=DarkRed,urlcolor=DarkBlue}
  ]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Berkeley}      

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{cleveref}

 \title[something]{something}
 \author{someone}
 \date{someday}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}{}
 \titlepage
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}{something}
 \href{http://google.com}{Google}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @unmark1: The usual way to say 'Thank you' is to accept the answer by clicking on the `checkmark` left on the answer post! ;-)